# Running spark scala example fails

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I'm new to both Spark and Scala. I've created an IntelliJ Scala project with SBT and added a few lines to build.sbt.

```
name := "test-one"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.1.0"
```

My version of Scala is 2.10.4 but this problem also occurs with 2.11.2

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
    at akka.util.Collections$EmptyImmutableSeq$.<init>(Collections.scala:15)
    at akka.util.Collections$EmptyImmutableSeq$.<clinit>(Collections.scala)
    at akka.japi.Util$.immutableSeq(JavaAPI.scala:209)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:150)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:470)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1446)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:203)
    at TweeProcessor$.main(TweeProcessor.scala:10)
    at TweeProcessor.main(TweeProcessor.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 23 more
```

Tried looking up online, most answers point to a mismatch between API versions and Scala version, but none are specific to Spark.

Answer (score 23):

`spark-core_2.10` is built for use with 2.10.x versions of scala. You should use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0"
```

which will select the correct _2.10 or _2.11 version for your scala version.

Also make sure you're compiling against the same versions of scala and spark as the ones on the cluster where you're running this.

Comment: Updated the code to use the dependency in the style you stated, both the client code and spark are using 2.10.4 and still this error is there. I'm guessing it's a classpath problem.

Comment: There's no spark-core for 2.11 yet.

Comment: I too face the same problem, I have Scala and spark as below:      scala-library:2.11.7  ;

spark-core_2.11:2.1.0  ;
spark-streaming_2.11:2.1.0  ;
spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.1.0   ;    Still same issue coming up

Comment: I have also updated kafka to kafka_2.11 from kafka_2.10 and issue is resolved now

Answer (score 10):

Downgrade the scala version to 2.10.4

```
name := "test-one"

version := "1.0"

//scalaVersion := "2.11.2"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.1.0"
```

Comment: Ran a "akka hello world" from alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-scala-akka-actor-examples-hello-world-actors and had same error. Setting to 2.10.4 worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version compatibility issue.
Spark_core 2.10 is build using scala 2.10, and your sbt file mention you are using scala 2.11. Either downgrade your scala version to 2.10 or upgrade your spark to 2.11

Comment: I too face the same problem, I have Scala and spark as below:      scala-library:2.11.7  ;

spark-core_2.11:2.1.0  ;
spark-streaming_2.11:2.1.0  ;
spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.1.0   ;    Still same issue coming up

Comment: I have also updated kafka to kafka_2.11 from kafka_2.10 and issue is resolved now

Answer (score 1):

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0",
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0"
         )
```

This configuration worked for me.