# Spark: ClassNotFoundException when running hello world example in scala 2.11

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an sbt project with subprojects. All of them use Scala 2.11.4. In one of the subprojects (sparktest) I added spark-core

```
name := """sparktest"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1"
    exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
)
```

sparktest depends on another sbt project called commons which overrides akka-actors to 2.3.9

The thing is, when I try to run the following snippet (pulled from spark examples)

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import scala.math.random

object SparkSpike extends App {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi").setMaster("local")
  val spark = new SparkContext(conf)

  val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2
  val n = math.min(100000L * slices, Int.MaxValue).toInt // avoid overflow
  val count = spark.parallelize(1 until n, slices).map { i =>
      val x = random * 2 - 1
      val y = random * 2 - 1
      if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
    }.reduce(_ + _)
  println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)
  spark.stop()
}
```

I get the following error:

```
2015-02-19 17:03:31,429 INFO o.a.s.SecurityManager Changing view acls to: bar
2015-02-19 17:03:31,432 INFO o.a.s.SecurityManager Changing modify acls to: bar
2015-02-19 17:03:31,433 INFO o.a.s.SecurityManager SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(bar); users with modify permissions: Set(bar)
2015-02-19 17:03:31,957 INFO a.e.s.Slf4jLogger Slf4jLogger started
2015-02-19 17:03:32,052 INFO Remoting Starting remoting
2015-02-19 17:03:32,336 INFO Remoting Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.59.3:49236]
2015-02-19 17:03:32,350 INFO o.a.s.u.Utils Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 49236.
2015-02-19 17:03:32,378 INFO o.a.s.SparkEnv Registering MapOutputTracker
2015-02-19 17:03:32,404 INFO o.a.s.SparkEnv Registering BlockManagerMaster
2015-02-19 17:03:32,440 INFO o.a.s.s.DiskBlockManager Created local directory at /var/folders/26/7b3b32gd4wx1h25vd2qm66q00000gp/T/spark-a594f880-f5d1-4926-b555-eabbe1728734/spark-4e8f77c4-8018-4e64-88e7-6ca060d9a35c
2015-02-19 17:03:32,447 INFO o.a.s.s.MemoryStore MemoryStore started with capacity 1891.5 MB
2015-02-19 17:03:32,948 WARN o.a.h.u.NativeCodeLoader Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-02-19 17:03:33,100 INFO o.a.s.HttpFileServer HTTP File server directory is /var/folders/26/7b3b32gd4wx1h25vd2qm66q00000gp/T/spark-0f30ec72-f2aa-44ed-9e92-9931fba5ba39/spark-d7fa24ef-768a-4e05-9fa3-ce29eacc0c19
2015-02-19 17:03:33,109 INFO o.a.s.HttpServer Starting HTTP Server
2015-02-19 17:03:33,206 INFO o.e.j.s.Server jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2015-02-19 17:03:33,229 INFO o.e.j.s.AbstractConnector Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:49237
2015-02-19 17:03:33,229 INFO o.a.s.u.Utils Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 49237.
2015-02-19 17:03:33,420 INFO o.e.j.s.Server jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2015-02-19 17:03:33,441 INFO o.e.j.s.AbstractConnector Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
2015-02-19 17:03:33,442 INFO o.a.s.u.Utils Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
2015-02-19 17:03:33,445 INFO o.a.s.u.SparkUI Started SparkUI at http://192.168.59.3:4040
2015-02-19 17:03:33,611 INFO o.a.s.e.Executor Starting executor ID <driver> on host localhost
2015-02-19 17:03:33,634 INFO o.a.s.u.AkkaUtils Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.59.3:49236/user/HeartbeatReceiver
2015-02-19 17:03:33,994 INFO o.a.s.n.n.NettyBlockTransferService Server created on 49238
2015-02-19 17:03:33,996 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManagerMaster Trying to register BlockManager
2015-02-19 17:03:33,998 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManagerMasterActor Registering block manager localhost:49238 with 1891.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 49238)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,001 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManagerMaster Registered BlockManager
2015-02-19 17:03:34,297 INFO o.a.s.SparkContext Starting job: reduce at SparkSpike.scala:17
2015-02-19 17:03:34,321 INFO o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler Got job 0 (reduce at SparkSpike.scala:17) with 2 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,322 INFO o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler Final stage: Stage 0(reduce at SparkSpike.scala:17)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,323 INFO o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler Parents of final stage: List()
2015-02-19 17:03:34,329 INFO o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler Missing parents: List()
2015-02-19 17:03:34,349 INFO o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler Submitting Stage 0 (MappedRDD[1] at map at SparkSpike.scala:13), which has no missing parents
2015-02-19 17:03:34,505 INFO o.a.s.s.MemoryStore ensureFreeSpace(1600) called with curMem=0, maxMem=1983365775
2015-02-19 17:03:34,507 INFO o.a.s.s.MemoryStore Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1600.0 B, free 1891.5 MB)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,588 INFO o.a.s.s.MemoryStore ensureFreeSpace(1171) called with curMem=1600, maxMem=1983365775
2015-02-19 17:03:34,588 INFO o.a.s.s.MemoryStore Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1171.0 B, free 1891.5 MB)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,591 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManagerInfo Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:49238 (size: 1171.0 B, free: 1891.5 MB)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,592 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManagerMaster Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
2015-02-19 17:03:34,594 INFO o.a.s.SparkContext Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:838
2015-02-19 17:03:34,617 INFO o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler Submitting 2 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MappedRDD[1] at map at SparkSpike.scala:13)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,618 INFO o.a.s.s.TaskSchedulerImpl Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
2015-02-19 17:03:34,659 INFO o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1260 bytes)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,671 INFO o.a.s.e.Executor Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,692 ERROR o.a.s.e.Executor Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1075)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
2015-02-19 17:03:34,704 INFO o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1260 bytes)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,704 INFO o.a.s.e.Executor Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,707 WARN o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1075)
    ... 20 more

2015-02-19 17:03:34,708 ERROR o.a.s.e.Executor Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1075)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
2015-02-19 17:03:34,711 ERROR o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
2015-02-19 17:03:34,731 INFO o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) on executor localhost: java.io.IOException (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range) [duplicate 1]
2015-02-19 17:03:34,733 INFO o.a.s.s.TaskSchedulerImpl Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
2015-02-19 17:03:34,742 INFO o.a.s.s.TaskSchedulerImpl Cancelling stage 0
2015-02-19 17:03:34,760 INFO o.a.s.s.DAGScheduler Job 0 failed: reduce at SparkSpike.scala:17, took 0.461929 s
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1078)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:182)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[error]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
[error]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1075)
[error]     ... 20 more
[error]
[error] Driver stacktrace:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.immutable.Range
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1075)
    ... 20 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:254)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:221)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last root/compile:runMain for the full output.
2015-02-19 17:03:34,793 ERROR o.a.s.ContextCleaner Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1550)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$3.run(ContextCleaner.scala:65)
2015-02-19 17:03:34,812 ERROR o.a.s.u.Utils Uncaught exception in thread SparkListenerBus
java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:996)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:317)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1550)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:46)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last root/compile:runMain for the full output.
[error] (root/compile:runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 31 s, completed Feb 19, 2015 12:03:35 PM
[foo-api] $ 2015-02-19 17:03:36,303 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManager Removing broadcast 0
2015-02-19 17:03:36,311 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManager Removing block broadcast_0
2015-02-19 17:03:36,313 INFO o.a.s.s.MemoryStore Block broadcast_0 of size 1600 dropped from memory (free 1983364604)
2015-02-19 17:03:36,313 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManager Removing block broadcast_0_piece0
2015-02-19 17:03:36,313 INFO o.a.s.s.MemoryStore Block broadcast_0_piece0 of size 1171 dropped from memory (free 1983365775)
2015-02-19 17:03:36,315 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManagerInfo Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on localhost:49238 in memory (size: 1171.0 B, free: 1891.5 MB)
2015-02-19 17:03:36,315 INFO o.a.s.s.BlockManagerMaster Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
2015-02-19 17:03:36,319 INFO o.a.s.ContextCleaner Cleaned broadcast 0
```

Note: that same setup worked in a fresh project. It's gotta be a conflict with my existing project, which is the one I want integrate with spark

Comment: This question explains the same symptoms and the solution was to downgrade to scala 2.10. The thing is, spark 1.2.0+ is meant to support scala 2.11
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351338/running-spark-scala-example-fails

Comment: But, did you build Spark for 2.11?

Comment: Justin, I am not building spark. I'm retrieving the jars from Mavem Central using sbt. spark-core has been built for scala 2.11 and published there
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spark-core_2.11%22

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently sbt was building some classes in scala 2.10 for a reason I failed to understand.

The solution was to use `fork := true` in the main `build.sbt`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23283286/351195)

Answer (score 1):

Had the very same issue, I had several libs on my classpath -- one was requiring scala 2.10.4 and the rest are 2.10.6, once I set scalaVersion on project level, the issue was gone:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
```