# Upgrade to Phantom cassandra 1.26 gives GenTraversableOnce$class error

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I was using phantom to connect to cassandra database from my scala code. It worked before. But today after I upgraded to the latest 1.26.1, it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at scala.reflect.internal.util.WeakHashSet.<init>(WeakHashSet.scala:19)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.WeakHashSet$.apply(WeakHashSet.scala:429)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable$perRunCaches$.<init>(SymbolTable.scala:310)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.perRunCaches$lzycompute(SymbolTable.scala:304)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.perRunCaches(SymbolTable.scala:304)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$class.$init$(Symbols.scala:71)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.<init>(SymbolTable.scala:13)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.<init>(JavaUniverse.scala:12)
at scala.reflect.runtime.package$.universe$lzycompute(package.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.runtime.package$.universe(package.scala:16)
at com.websudos.diesel.engine.reflection.EarlyInit$class.$init$(EarlyInit.scala:13)
at com.websudos.phantom.db.DatabaseImpl.<init>(DatabaseImpl.scala:42)
at data.MyDatabase.<init>(Users.scala:87)
```

I'm using scala 2.11.7. Strange enough that downgraded to the older version the issue remains. I know it must be something else. But I couldn't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: Hi @yang, this is very strange and it's more than likely local to your machine. I would try to clean the proejct I'm working in or alternatively try and flush the ivy cache the old fashioned way. `rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache`. 

Looks like an impedance mismatch, a relatively strange one.

Comment: Found some similar questions: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351338/running-spark-scala-example-fails) I downgraded the scala version to 2.10.4. The problem goes away. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @flavian remove the cache dir doesn't help.

Comment: Try a more recent version like 1.28.5, I'm hoping the problem was fixed in the process by bumping versions. Sounds like something to do with Scala reflection.